# Importing PBR models into Xcode results in incorrect shader properties

Tags: xcode, scenekit, collada, .obj, usdz

I have been experimenting with different 3D model file formats in Xcode, primarily **.obj** and **.dae**.

However, after I export these files from Blender, they either don't have any lighting associated with them or all of the values (especially their metalness and roughness) are not what they were initially setup to be.

[image: OBJ file imported, with all parameters maxed out and completely white]

[image: Similar for the Collada file, though more with the metalness]

[image: This is how I expect the models to render in Xcode (screenshot taken from Blender)]

.obj export,
.dae export,
then the blender version.

Is the issue how I'm exporting the models from Blender, the models themselves, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

## obj

If you create a model in Blender (or in Maya), remember, every app has its own internal shaders that may differ from SceneKit's shaders. When you export any model as `.obj` you also get a corresponding uv-mapped `.mtl` texture file. There are no lights inside `.obj`, because this format does support only geometry (with smoothness, normals and UV IDs). And one more thing – `.obj` doesn't support animation.

## dae

`.dae` format allows you export not only 3D geometry with animations but also its corresponding shaders (like Phong, Blinn or Lambert) with colours and textures (however, Blender or Maya's procedural textures are not supported). And all the lights that were in 3D scene will be also exported.

## usdz

The best candidate for export is `.usdz` file. Not all 3D authoring tools have `export usdz` option, but Autodesk Maya 2022, thanks to USD plugin, has.

`.usdz` format has all the features that `.dae` format has, but in addition to that I can say it's native to RealityKit, SceneKit, Reality Composer and QuickLook, its hierarchical system was adapted for larger scenes and it supports Python USDZ schemas.